# Superheat Use Given Cluster Group

Tags: r, heatmap

I generated dendrogram and have obtained k clusters. I wanted to obtain heatmap by using the existing dendrogram and clusters. I want to display my heatmap in multiple pages so I did them one by one in separate calls. To make the colour chart comparable, I also set pal.values. Here’s my code sample:

```
sh <- superheat(X = cbind(dt[grep("Action", colnames(dt))], profile),
                heat.pal = brewer.pal(8, 'RdBu')[8:1],
                heat.pal.values = c(-1.4:2.3),
                bottom.label = 'variable',
                grid.hline.col = '#F0EBEB',
                grid.vline.col = '#F0EBEB',
                smooth.heat = TRUE,
                membership.rows = hc$cluster,
                column.title = 'factors', row.title = 'Clusters',
                bottom.label.text.size = 1.5, bottom.label.text.angle = 90)
sh$membership.rows == hc$cluster
```

From there, when I did checking if the memberships are matched, its displayed a mix of TRUE AND FALSE. I couldn’t find out what’s wrong with my code. Would you please enlighten me?